# Why check the boolean value of Array.prototype.indexOf?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In Fabric.js you see a lot of places where a code block enclosed in a condition check of format:

`if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {}` or

`if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {}` etc.

Isn't the result always false? Why checking the boolean value of a method?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand truthy values in JavaScript.

Comment: @epascarello I guess I don't really since you asked. I do know `!!undefined == false`, however didn't make the connection in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those tests pass when the functions aren't defined.

Old browsers don't have those functions. That's why they're testing for their presence.

[The MDN gives the same example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (classical) of this test used to define a replacement function for array.indexOf (for IE before version 9) :

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
        "use strict";
        if (this == null) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        var n = 0;
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            n = Number(arguments[1]);
            if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
                n = 0;
            } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
            }
        }
        if (n >= len) {
            return -1;
        }
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
        for (; k < len; k++) {
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is checking for the existence of the method. If it doesn't exist, it will be `undefined`, so it'll be doing `!undefined`, resulting in `true`.

I would assume that the code is introducing a shim if it doesn't exist.